# Is there a similar method to HttpResponse.ApplyAppPathModifier?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I need to run some code on the `Application_Start` which uses [HttpResponse.ApplyAppPathModifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.applyapppathmodifier(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

I'm using `IIS7` + `Integrated mode` and there is no HttpResponse object **by design**.

Since I can't get my hand on the HttpResponse object during the `Application_Start`, I'd be glad to find a similar method to [HttpResponse.ApplyAppPathModifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.applyapppathmodifier(v=vs.110).aspx).